# Using onTouch/onClick to change canvas drawing displayed on Android

Tags: java, android

I have a canvas drawing, I am going to use onTouch to change the colour of the drawing. It is a house, and on touching the screen once it will change to a darker shade. I have only been told that I will need to move the method calls into dayTime and nightTime, switchable by boolean, and that the text daytime and night time has to be rendered on the image accordingly.

Below is the code I used to draw the image. Any help on how to finish this would be appreciated:

```
/*
 * DrawView.java 
 */
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener
{

    private Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_grass = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_door = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_house = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_roof = new Paint();
    private Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
    private Paint circlePaint_sun = new Paint();
    private Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    private Paint path = new Paint();
    private Path trianglePath;
    private float sx, sy;

    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);         

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(135,250,205));
        backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        backgroundPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_grass.setColor(Color.rgb(124, 252, 0));
        drawPaint_grass.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_door.setColor(Color.RED);
        drawPaint_door.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        //drawPaint_.setColor(Color.RED);
        //drawPaint_door.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_house.setColor(Color.rgb(205, 133, 63));
        drawPaint_house.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_roof.setColor(Color.rgb(160, 82, 45));
        drawPaint_roof.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        circlePaint_sun.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0));
        circlePaint_sun.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        trianglePath = new Path();
        trianglePath.moveTo(70, 300); // starting point
        trianglePath.lineTo(170,250); // 1st vertix
        trianglePath.lineTo(270, 300); // 2nd vertix
        trianglePath.lineTo(70, 300); // 3rd vertix and close
        //path.moveTo(getRight()/2, getLeft()/2, getTop()/2, getBottom()/2);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        //255, 255, 240
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.rgb(211, 211, 211));
        circlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        // Draw white background
        canvas.drawRect(this.getLeft(), this.getTop(), this.getRight(), this.getBottom(), backgroundPaint);

        //draw a rectangle with blue paint
        canvas.drawRect(0,400, 540,600, drawPaint_grass); 
        canvas.drawRect(100,400, 240,300, drawPaint_house);
        canvas.drawRect(150,400, 190,335, drawPaint_door); 
        canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, drawPaint_roof); 

        //draw text with green paint
        canvas.drawText("Muhibur Rahim", 232, 565, textPaint);

        //draw a circle with red paint with the touch coordinates
        canvas.drawCircle(sx-30,sy-30, 3, circlePaint);

        canvas.drawCircle(80, 80, 30, circlePaint_sun);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {   
        //update the coordinates for the OnDraw method above, with wherever we touch
        sx = event.getX();
        sy = event.getY();

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

I was thinking of putting the colouring part of code (circlePaint_sun.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0)) into methods (eg. static void dayTime() under private Drawview(Context, Context), and then assigning the two methods values 0 and 1, and on touch or click (i think onclick would be better) a counter increases and the values alternate between 0 and 1. However I am not sure how to use that in a code after repeated tries, any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Add a `private boolean dark = false;` to your variables.

In your `onDraw` method, add something like

```
if (dark) backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
else backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
```

before you draw your background.

Change your boolean inside the `onTouch` method:

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
   dark = !dark;
   DrawView();
}
```

Comment: You have to change the onDraw method, not the constructor (the updated answer is now correct)

Comment: However the details of all the colours is in the constructor and not the onDraw() method?

Comment: Those colors that dont need to be changed can be set in the constructor. The background color has to be updated everytime the image is drawn so you need to do it in the `onDraw` method before you draw the background.